# Powerpoint VBA, Shape deletion during For Each loop skips next item

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm lopping through the shapes in Slide 1 of Powerpoint

**When Shape with name "HD" gets deleted next shape is becoming "SD" skipping "4K". And if "4K" is deleted then next shape is becoming "FullHD"**

**how to avoide this?**

```
For Each pshape In ppres.Slides(1).Shapes
    Select Case pshape.Name
        Case "HD"
            Debug.Print vbTab & pshape.Name
            If LCase(Cells(2, titleHeader.ListColumns("Nature of Material*").Index)) <> "hd" And LCase(Cells(2, titleHeader.ListColumns("Nature of Material*").Index)) = "" Then
                pshape.Delete
            End If
        Case "4K"
            Debug.Print vbTab & pshape.Name
            If LCase(Cells(2, titleHeader.ListColumns("Nature of Material*").Index)) <> "4k" And LCase(Cells(2, titleHeader.ListColumns("Nature of Material*").Index)) = "" Then
                pshape.Delete
            End If
        Case "SD"
            Debug.Print vbTab & pshape.Name
        Case "FullHD"
            Debug.Print vbTab & pshape.Name
            Debug.Print vbTab & Cells(2, titleHeader.ListColumns("FullHD").Index)
    End Select
Next
```

**Update 1: Tried (Not Working)**
What could be the problem here ?

```
Dim countShape as Long
Dim i as Long
countShape = ppres.Slides(1).Shapes.count
For i = 1 to countShape
    Select Case pshape.Name
        Case "HD"
            Debug.Print vbTab & pshape.Name
            pshape.Delete
            i = i - 1
            countShape = countShape - 1
        Case "4K"
            Debug.Print vbTab & pshape.Name
            pshape.Delete
            i = i - 1
            countShape = countShape - 1
        Case "SD"
            Debug.Print vbTab & pshape.Name
        Case "FullHD"
            Debug.Print vbTab & pshape.Name
    End Select
Next i
```

**Integer Out of Range Error is coming.
I think countShape is not updating it's value.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to loop through your shapes by index and from last to first...

```
Dim i As Long

With ppres.Slides(1).Shapes
    For i = .Count To 1 Step -1
        Select Case .Item(i).Name
            'etc
            '
            '
        End Select
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Would this actually iterate through in a different order than the `For each...` loop?

Comment: Yes, it would loop backwards, starting from the last shape in the collection to the first one.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about that behavior, thanks

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Imagine the `For each` as a loop from 1 to count, when you delete the first, the others get reindexed.

Comment: @user3819867 Wouldn't it loop from index of count to 1 if it loops in reverse?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Yes, as Domenic mentioned already. But if you loop in reverse and delete, say, shape 42, it won't change the indices of shapes 41 and lower, whereas if you loop forward and delete shape 42, then shape 43 has become 42 but your loop will have you examining shape 43 next and look at what was previously shape 44. You'll skip stuff.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg **oh** gosh, when I wrote my original question I was still seeing the order as looping from first to last, so I totally get why I was confusing everyone - what a brainfart. When I responded "Interesting, I didn't know about that behavior, thanks", my understanding at that moment was that the `For each ..` loop was ordered in reverse whereas (in my head) this answer was looping forwards.

Comment: @Domenic I was trying different approach to get the same result. But, it didn't worked can you tell me why...I'm posting the code again...

Comment: In both your examples, you're looping forward, so when you delete a shape the indices for subsequent shapes will change, as @SteveRindsberg has already explained.  So you need to loop backwards.

Comment: @VinodBokde I gave Domenic's answer another tick for you. ;-)